# Can't import import com.google.android.glass.media.CameraManager in Eclipse

Tags: android, google-glass

I can't seem to import this library in Eclipse anymore. I looked GDK guide to see if they note that CameraManager has been deprecated or discontinued (maybe I'm just not looking in the right place?). Even https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/media/CameraManager just gives me a 404 error. So I don't know if this is no longer part of the API or if something's just wonky with my Eclipse setup.

Any help is appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extras that previously existing in `CameraManager` have been moved to the [Intents](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/content/Intents) class as per the [XE 18.1 release notes](https://developers.google.com/glass/release-notes#xe18.1) and the class has since been removed from the GDK.